# how to pass style css from parent component to child component vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

My Parent :

```
<template>
   <div> 
     <p class="my-class">Hello world.</p>
     <Child/>
 </div>
<template>

import Child from "@/components/Child.vue";

<style scoped>
  .my-class{
    font-size: 18px;
  }
</style>
```

What'd be the child vue? to load scoped style CSS in my Child.Vue component.

Comment: have you tried adding `class="my-class"` to `Child`? What happens next will amaze you :p

Comment: By removing `scoped` from the definition of your style then the class becomes global and can be used everywhere, not just its children.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the deep selector in scoped css block to apply the class to the component's children components.
See [the docs](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-css-features.html#deep-selectors)

In your case the css portion of the SFC would turn to something along the lines of:

```
<style scoped>
::v-deep(.my-class) {
  font-size: 18px;
}
</style>
```